# Can Clang formatting be used in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans-8, clang-format

Is there a way to use the clang formatter with NetBeans 8.1? I'm running NetBeans on Arch Linux, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you posted your question the answer was no, but now (over a year later!) you can use the clang formatter in NetBeans, subject to the following constraints:

1. You must use version 8.2 of NetBeans rather than version 8.1.
2. You must install from a [recent nightly development build](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) of NetBeans 8.2 rather than using the standard release. That's because this functionality was only added recently. See [NetBeans bug 270882](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=270882).

To use the clang formatter in NetBeans:

- Create a trivial C++ application in NetBeans.
- Select its project node in the **Projects** tab, right click, and select **Properties** from the popup menu.
- In the **Project Properties** window that opens click **Formatting** in the list of categories.
- On the right side of the screen there is a new radio button named **Use clang-format**. Click that, and you can then either use a predefined style, or supply your own customized format file, as shown in the screen shot below.

[image]