# Netbeans with clang-format

Tags: netbeans-8, clang-format

How to use clang-format with Netbeans.
I need to run clang-format when the currently edited file is saved.
thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384787/can-clang-formatting-be-used-in-netbeans/46765258#46765258 (although you asked first).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Clang formatting be used in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384787/can-clang-formatting-be-used-in-netbeans)