# Can clang-format be used in Netbeans versions greater than 8.2

Tags: c++, netbeans, clang-format

I am currently using newest Netbeans version 17 with C/C++ plugin from Netbeans 8.2 Plugin Portal.

Is there a way to use `clang-format` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765258/4473840)?

When I open project properties -> Formatting, I can choose between *"Use global formatting style"* and *"Use project specific formatting style"* but **not** *"Use clang-format"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [the answer that you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765258/2985643), and unfortunately the situation is that it is no longer possible to use clang-format in NetBeans. It's possible to be definitive about this because you are (understandably) trying to use the old C/C++ plugin from NetBeans 8.x, but that plugin is specifically no longer supported.

A fairly recent Apache NetBeans Bug Report ([Unable to build c/c++ EFL](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4925)) has nothing to do with your specific problem, but it contains these authoritative comments from the NetBeans team with regard to the old C/C++ plugin:

> The C/C++ plugin is not part of the Apache NetBeans project, so we
> can't do anything about issues with it directly. This code may be
> released by Apache NetBeans in future.

> ...there is a branch here with the code already (it was always
> open-source, and was donated) - it's just not in a releasable state.
> https://github.com/apache/netbeans/tree/cnd

It's a shame because that plugin worked well, and the currently supported alternative (the CPPLite plugin) is not as good. I don't know for sure, but I suspect that the old plugin is no longer supported for licensing/legal reasons associated with NetBeans moving to Apache rather than any technical issues.

So if you have somehow got the old C/C++ plugin working with NetBeans 17, just bear in mind that its use is unsupported, and this may not be the only functionality issue you encounter.